# How do I add an option to a dynamic number of select boxes and redirect the browser if and only if the added option is selected utilizing jquery/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I have currently.  The URL validator is only there because this thing was redirecting on ANY option selected and the ONLY time I want a redirect triggered is when the options I add with jquery are clicked.

Here's my HTML:

```
<select data-select-size-key="0" id="popular_sizes_0" name="popular_sizes_0">!!OptiONS CONtAINED HERE!!</select>
```

and my JS:

```
var customSizeOption = "<option value='"+"https://url.com"+"'>Size Not Listed?</option>";
$("[id^=popular_sizes_]").append(customSizeOption);

function validateURL(textval) {
    var urlregex = /^(https?|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9.&%$-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(:[0-9]+)*(\/($|[a-zA-Z0-9.,?'\\+&%$#=~_-]+))*$/;
    return urlregex.test(textval);
}

$(function(){
  // bind change event to select
  $("[id^=popular_sizes_]").on('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
      if (validateURL(url)) { // require a URL
          window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      return false;
  });
});
```

And [here's CodePen for it](http://codepen.io/nicoleredux/pen/WxgzJp).

NOTE:  the _0 auto-increments up to 12 select boxes per page

Comment: HTML missing in the codepen?

Comment: added to codepen.  Sorry

Comment: Well, if you want redirection by JS (and selecting) and not by selecting by a user, what's the point to do smth with the selection at all? (that's what I can see from the question title)

Comment: I only took out the options for ease of code.  There's 60 other options generated through ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but the `select` has no other `option`, so there is no change event if you add a default (blank) `option` and run the code it works.

```
<select data-select-size-key="0" id="popular_sizes_0" name="popular_sizes_0">
<option></option>
</select>
```

Now if you change the option, the validation and redirection works.